# Can't read Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have 2 fairly new SATA hard drives that I'm moving to a new machine. One was the boot drive, the other had all 'My Stuff' on it. Both drives were installed under Ubuntu 12.04

I need to copy the contents of the 'My Stuff' drive to the other drive.

So new parts (i5, Asus Z97e Mobo, Asus GTX 970 & RAM)

I couldn't remember which was the boot drive, & accidentally installed Ubuntu 14.04 to the 'My Stuff' drive instead of the boot drive. Not a problem, it made a new partition & I could still access everything.

So I removed the 'My Stuff' drive from the machine, leaving just the original boot drive, which I wiped & installed Win10 on.

I then added the 'My Stuff' drive back in, but could not boot from it. Windows could not read it, disk manager showed the partitions but I didn't do anything.

I then ran Ubuntu 14.04 from a flash drive, hoping to access the 'My Stuff' drive & copy the contents over to the (Windows) boot drive.
BUT I can't access any of the 'My Stuff' drive; I apparently don't have the necessary permissions. Apparently the owner is the other drive.

I know about backing up data I want to keep, it was backed up, a full copy was on the other drive (which is now wiped), & most of it was also backed up to a 12 year old PATA drive (which I have got working via USB caddy) but it is completely full with no room for some of the data I wanted to keep.

I also tried putting the 'My Stuff' drive into the USB caddy (which can do PATA & SATA) & tried under Win10 (from HDD) & also tried from Ubuntu (from flash drive) but I just cant access the drive. No permission under Ubuntu & Win10 just cant see it.

I eventually want to run dual boot Win10 & Ubuntu 14.04, but I need to copy some of the contents of the 'My Stuff' drive to the other drive first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 2):

Try to copy your files as root of your Live-Ubuntu-drive

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo -i 
nautilus
```

to open the file manager as root. When done, in the terminal type

```
exit
```

to drop privileges.

Comment: I dont know how to get root access, I dont know enough about Ubuntu to do that.
I havent used any commands yet.

Comment: So you did everything with the gui?
Open a terminal and type `sudo nautilus` to open the file manager as root